# Preserving dates python

Tags: python, date, datetime, dataframe

I have a table I pull in by using:

```
df = pd.read_sas('date.sas7bdat')
```

once I pull this .sas7bdat file in it changes all of my date fields to number like 16372 instead of bringing them in as they were in the sas table. The way they looked before being pulled into my df were 31oct2017. Is their anyway to preserve them when they get read in.

Comment: Are you saying it's converting `31oct2017` to `16372`?

Comment: Yes, when I read that sas7bdat file in for some reason it reads in my date fields as numbers and not like how it looked like in the original file.